# Tension on a string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, string

A string is attached at both extremities and put under tension $T_0$ at rest. We know that if we pull the string upwards from the middle, the tension will increase. But why is it that, admittedly, $$T\cos(\alpha) = T_0$$ or $$T = \frac{T_0}{\cos(\alpha)}~ ?$$

I understand the trigonometry, but Why is the new tension directly proportional to $\frac{1}{\cos(\alpha)}$ ? Is it that obvious ? I would have imagined something involving the length change and the material properties like elasticity ...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation you quote is an approximation that is only valid if the horizontal force on the string remains the same. In practice that is not the case - and your concern is valid.

The increase in length $\Delta \ell =\ell(\frac{1}{\cos\theta}-1)$; how much additional force that generates depends on the unstretched length of the string (or equivalently on its elastic coefficient) since $\Delta T = k(\ell - \ell_0)$ where $\ell_0$ is the unstretched length.

It follows that while $\Delta T = k \Delta \ell$ the original tension is not $k\ell$ so the equality is not exact. But for small displacements it is usually good enough.

When I have a chance I will add some diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, tension force itself depends on the elastic/rigid property of the string. So, the properties are implicit in the mathematical representation of the tension.

Let a small part of the string be acted by tension $T_0$ from both sides of the string & hence it remains in static equilibrium as in the first picture.

Now, when that part is stretched, the restoring force in the form of vertical-component of tension from both sides ie. $2T_0 \sin\alpha$ brings back or tends to return that part to its original status. Now, the horizontal component $T_0\cos\alpha$ from one side of the string is balanced by the same from the other side; otherwise there would be horizontal acceleration which can't be!

So, tension $T_0$ remains same.
$T_0 \cos\alpha$ is just the horizontal component of otherwise same magnitude but **differently oriented original tension vector**.